# Does a developer's job affect their performance on certain tasks?

Tags: game-dev-story

I just got through my first 20-year game. I ended up with several Hackers on my team, because they all seem to have amazingly high attributes (300s-400s on each stat).  However, despite looking so great, their performance on proposals, graphics, sound and boosts felt a bit...underwhelming.

My gut feeling is that you might get better results with, say, a lower-stat Writer or Director coming up with your proposal, or a Sound Eng. for sound, rather than someone with high stats and an unrelated job. Unfortunately, I didn't have much time left in my game to really test this. **Does job title affect a developer's performance on related tasks, or is their performance entirely based on their relevant attributes?**

Comment: This totally *sounds* off topic, at first glance.

Comment: Why would this be off-topic? He's asking about a particular game mechanic in a game, seems like it should be on-topic for this site.

Comment: @sarge_smith The question title, taken without context, sounds like an extremely vague question about managing software developers.

Comment: @sjo true... you should add the words "in game dev story" to the end of it.

Comment: I'd also love to know the answer to this question; my hackers also seem to underperform.

Comment: My hackers are also not always available as an option in all categories, even if they have 200/300 in all categories.  It's weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were correct in your own assumptions:

- Job Title is there for a reason! That person is good at a specific task, and should be used as such. However, the same worker should *never* be used on two games in a row.
- Choosing a worker with a high stat for a task he wasn't meant to do (IE: Choosing Sound Manager for Writing) is never worth it. It's not possible to get enough stats to make up for the deficit. The worker will be unfocused and perform poorly.
- Hackers should never be left as Hackers. Buy a Career Change Manual from the salesman and give them a role based job. Yes their stats will drop slightly, but it will still be worth it.

One of the best guides I found for the game while I was playing it is [this one](http://www.diygamer.com/2010/10/game-dev-story-guide/). Most of these points I learned from that site, and they cover a lot more as well.